# How do I read the versioning for NPM dependencies

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I got the below output when trying to install the latest version of `webpack`. To me, it reads that version `5.0.0` should be allowed since it is >=2 but am I reading it wrong?

Error:

```
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.0.0-rc.6
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   webpack@"5.0.0-rc.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.1.0
```

Similarly:

```
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.44.2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@">=4.43.0 <6.0.0" from babel-loader@8.1.0
```

Comment: I think a release candidate version won't match a selector for released versions. Is there a reason you're trying to use a version of Webpack that is _not yet officially released_?